# Placing multiple divs in two columns without container divs / wrappers

Tags: html, css

I hope you can help me out with a CSS problem I'm trying to solve.

I have a set of divs, let's say 4 for this example. I want to structure them in two vertical columns on a page, *without* using container divs around each of the columns.

However (here's the tricky part), I want them to be arranged so that each div falls exactly below the one above it. At the moment, I've got it so that they line up with each other along the top.

**[Take a look here for the code & example](http://cssdesk.com/UDQVd)**.

It works fine *unless* one of the divs on the left is longer than the div on the right, as shown in the example.

So... my problem is. How do I get it so that the green box is positioned directly underneath the blue box, rather than inline with the top of the yellow box.

*I don't want to use `margin-top: -60px` or similar*.

Using JavaScript/jQuery is fine if necessary, but a pure CSS solution would be ideal.

The important thing to remember is that **I can't use container divs around the columns**.

I'm not even sure this is possible, and have wasted a day trying to get it to work... if you could help, I would be very grateful - even if you just confirm it isn't possible!

Comment: Is it possible that you want a `<table>`? While `<table>`s should not be used for layouts, it's perfectly fine for certain types of data. What actual content is going to occupy these boxes?

Comment: No, sorry should have made that clearer. Each div will be filled with a type of content - e.g. one will have lots of text, another might have an image, or a video. So no, a table would not be suitable, but thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 solutions, **CSS3** and no support for older browsers, or a **jQuery plugin**.

### With [CSS3 Columns](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/columns2.html)

```
#wrapper{
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 10px;
}
```

Or for greater compatibility, with vendor prefixes:

```
#wrapper{
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    column-gap: 10px;
}
```

[**View example on CSSDesk**](http://cssdesk.com/vASvk)

### with jQuery plugins

1. As @allaire noted, [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) in an excellent library.
2. Then there is [Wookmark](http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin), havent tested it but looks very clean.
3. Or this [jQuery.column](http://www.vanderlee.com/martijn/?page_id=229) plugin that mimics the CSS3 column behavior. (havent tried this one yet either)

And there are a lot more plugins that do columnizing, search around for [masonry alternatives](https://www.google.nl/search?q=masonry%20alternatives) to find your pick.

Answer (score 0):

I once did something similar and came to the conclusion to use jQuery, here's the plugin I used, worked well:

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

here is a pure html/css way to do it.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

.container {
  position: relative;
}
div.box {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
div.box:nth-child(odd) {
  margin-right: 1px;
}
div.box:nth-child(even) {
  margin-left: -1px;
}
```

the margin-left and margin-right on the boxes makes sure a left box cannot float next to a left box.